# When is variable taken into account if variable assignment is not followed by a semicolon?

Tags: bash

When I execute `var=blah echo -n $var`, then nothing is printed which is an expected behavior because `bash` first expands `$var` with an empty string, then sets up a temporary environment and puts `var=blah` in it and finally `echo` runs with an empty string as an argument. On the other hand, when I execute `IFS=. read a b <<< "k.l"`, then new value for `IFS` is taken into account. When is variable taken into account if variable statement is not followed by a semicolon?

Comment: You ran this as separate commands I suppose with the `;` separator? or on separate lines in commandline, `var=blah;echo -n $var` will produce the value of `$var`

Comment: Pay attention on the different outputs of the following commands: `var=blah bash -c "echo $var"`  and `var=blah bash -c 'echo $var' `.

Comment: `IFS` is set for the environment before `read` is run, just as `var` is set before `echo` is run. The expansion of variables happens as the line is interpreted though before either of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An assignment or several in a simple command by themselves cause the variables to be set as variables in the shell. If they are exported, they'll be inherited to the environment of any commands the shell executes.

An assignment in a simple command with an actual command to run does *not* change the variable in the shell, but only sets it in the environment of the command being executed. (A "simple command" is the usual kind of command, as opposed to a pipeline or a compound command. See the [standard for the definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09).)

Let's compare a couple of situations with a test script:

```
$ cat test.sh
echo "var: $var"            # print 'var' from the environment
echo "arg: $1"              # print the first command line arg

$ unset var
```

Here, `var` is set in the environment of `test.sh`, but the shell doesn't have that variable, so the one on the command line expands to nothing:

```
$ var=foo sh test.sh "$var" 
var: foo
arg:
```

Here, `var` is set in the shell, so the one on the command line is expanded, but it's *not* set in the `test.sh`'s environment:

```
$ var=foo; sh test.sh "$var"            
var: 
arg: foo
```

If we export it, it goes to the environment, too:

```
$ export var; sh test.sh "$var"
var: foo
arg: foo
```

Conceptually, you could think of `read` as a program like any other, so `IFS` set on the same command line is inherited to it, and affects the how `read` works. Similarly to `var` above.

Though `IFS` and `read` are slightly exceptional in that Bash doesn't inherit `IFS` from the environment (`dash` does), but resets it, and  `IFS` isn't exported by default but `IFS=.; read a` still causes `read` to use the changed `IFS`. Of course `read` is a builtin, so it sees the shell's variables, not just the exported ones. I can't think of any other shell builtin that would use `IFS` similarly, so I can't compare.

Answer (score 0):

`read` always reads a single line of input, regardless of how many arguments it is given; once the line is read, `read` itself uses the value of `IFS` in its environment to split the string into enough words to populate the variables named by its positional arguments.